# AWK search and parsing data in a loop

Tags: awk

i have a command with multiple lines and find the details

```
runmqsc -cert -details -pw test1 -db 123.kdb -label "Mahendra1"
```

output :

```
label : mahendra1
issuer : cn=mahendra2, OS=abcd
subject :
----------
=mahendra3, os=hkjkj 
Not Before : 10 oct 2013
not after :  20 oct 2014
```

now i have to extract the issuer value from the above command (mahendra2) and have to next iteration command.

```
runmqsc -cert -details -pw test1 -db 123.kdb -label "Mahendra2"
```

output :

```
label : mahendra2
issuer : cn=mahendra3, OS=abcd
subject :CN=mahendra4, os=hkjkj 
Not Before : 10 oct 2014
not after :  20 oct 2015
```

at one point of time issuer and subject values will be same. i.e may 5-6 iterations.

```
label : mahendra5
issuer : cn=mahendra6, OS=abcd
subject :CN=mahendra6, os=hkjkj 
Not Before : 10 oct 2014
not after :  20 oct 2015
```

is there any way to execute in awk ?

Comment: So you want to loop the `runmqsc` command until the `issuer` and `subject` lines match (or match on `cn=`)?  Or do you only want to perform 5-6 iterations total?  Do you want to keep the information from each iteration somewhere or do you only need the last copy?  What have you tried?

Comment: yes, i want to end the loop of runmqsc command to end until issuer and subject lines match

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question:

```
is there any way to execute in awk ?
```

It's more than likely you can execute this with awk.  I actually have an older gawk linked in as awk.  I was curious if it could be done entirely with "awk" so here we are.

Note that this is *a complete abuse of awk* because awk is designed to work over input files.  However, if you put all of the logic into the `BEGIN` block, what you asked for is technically possible.  I don't have your command, so I mocked up the behavior using `cat` with files named with your `label` and issuer fields.  I put the following into a file called `abuse`:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    label="mahendra1"
    # j is a safety so you do not infinitely loop
    while( abuseAwk( withCmdForLabel() ) && ++j < 10 ) {
        # do nothing here
    }
}

# There is no input file, so the body will never execute anything.
# This is *why* this script is an abuse of awk
# Putting commands here would cause awk to "hang", while waiting for input
# An END block would also "hang" for the same reason.

function abuseAwk( cmd ) {
    printf( "cmd = %s\n", cmd )
    while( cmd | getline ) {
        FS="="  # set this here after getline has assigned $0
        if( $0 ~ /^issuer/ ) { i = $2; sub( /,.*$/, "", i ); label = i }
        if( $0 ~ /^subject/ ) { s = $2; sub( /,.*$/, "", s ) }
    }
    close( cmd )

    return( i != s )
}

# you could rewrite the sprintf for your command
function withCmdForLabel() { return( sprintf( "cat %s", label ) ) }
```

and `chmod +x abuse` to make it executable.  The first `label` was hard-coded to keep this purely in the realm of awk.  It's only output is the form of the command as it's run in the `abuseAwk()` function.

A *much* better choice would be to use bash or another scripting language to perform the loop over commands( which could feed a very simple awk script then ), and you should *never* put this code into production.